# Setting AlarmManager Time onClick android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i am trying to change the **AlarmManager**'s time to 1 day, 3 days and 7 days on the click of respective buttons. for instance, if i click on "1 day" button, the alarm should be set in a way that it repeats every day and so on. but i have no idea how to achieve this, i have the code for repeating alarm with pre defined time

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        long recurring = (1 * 60000 * 60 * 24); // repeat every 24 hrs
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis(), recurring, sender);
    }

    public void set1day(View view) {
        //...
    }

    public void set3days(View view) {
        //...
    }

    public void set7days(View view) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are default constants available for interval day. You should use them instead of calculating seconds for intervals. like this one:

for single day interval

```
 public void set1day(View view) {      
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, sender);
}
```

for 3 days interval

```
public void set3day(View view) { 
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
                .getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*3, sender);
}
```

for any n days interval

```
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar.getInstance()
            .getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*n, sender);
```

Also, as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. Use `setInexactRepeating` to avoid battery drain.